# How does MongoDB store user passwords

Tags: mongodb, authentication, cryptography

When I query the collection storing users in a MongoDB database I get a document like this

`{
  "_id": "admin.123",
  "user": "123",
  "db": "admin",
  "credentials": {
    "SCRAM-SHA-1": {
      "iterationCount": 10000,
      "salt": "f9SdPCCcBOwk71/xDkj6Sw==",
      "storedKey": "83mNhTYctOdlYsL1sbnfpiA0uxw=",
      "serverKey": "09H9aEKKufaoCDxqUkHntx6EqrE="
    }
  },
  "roles": []
}`

- How is this data used to authenticate a user? I get the salt is
  stored in base64 and iterationCount is the amount of times it is
  concatenated to itself but what do both key fields represent?
- Is this information even publicly available as I couldn't find
  anything in the docs?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/Pi2d8nehCXQ

Comment: @dnickless FYI: that mongodb-user discussion is from 2011 and appears to be users musing on how to implement their own encryption rather than MongoDB's implementation at the time ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB supports multiple [authentication mechanisms](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication-mechanisms/) including SCRAM-SHA-1, X.509, and MONGODB-CR in the Community server as well as GSSAPI (Kerberos) and LDAP in the Enterprise server edition.

As of MongoDB 3.0, the default authentication mechanism for MongoDB is [SCRAM-SHA-1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-scram-sha-1/), which replaces the former proprietary MONGODB-CR challenge-response authentication. SCRAM-SHA-1 is an IETF standard -- the implementation details can be found in [RFC-5802: Salted Challenge Response Authentication Mechanism (SCRAM) SASL and GSS-API Mechanisms](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5802).

> How is this data used to authenticate a user?

As with other cryptographic [challenge/response protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge%E2%80%93response_authentication), the general approach is that the server sends an authentication challenge that requires a client to compute a correct answer as proof of a secret (the password) without ever providing the actual plaintext password. As part of the protocol, the client and server exchange some details about variables required to compute the correct answer (such as the `salt` and `iterationCount`) according to the authentication algorithm.

The fields stored for MongoDB's SCRAM-SHA-1 credentials are:

- `iterationCount`: an iteration count for key derivation
- `salt`: a per-user randomly generated salt to be used during key derivation
- `StoredKey`:  used by the server to verify the client's identity
- `ServerKey`:  used by the server to prove its identity to the client

For more information on MongoDB's implementation see *Improved Password-Based Authentication in MongoDB 3.0: SCRAM* [part 1](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/improved-password-based-authentication-mongodb-30-scram-explained-part-1) and [part 2](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/improved-password-based-authentication-mongodb-30-scram-explained-part-2).